# Fetching NWS API in Google Apps Script 500 Error

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, http-headers, geojson

I'm trying to get NWS Alerts from [their new GeoJSON API](https://forecast-v3.weather.gov/documentation), but am getting a 500 error when fetching via Google Apps Script.

```js
function getAlerts() {
  var rawData = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active', {muteHttpExceptions: true});
  Logger.log(rawData);
}
```

Log:

```js
{
  "correlationId": "085cf198-e7ee-427c-8bb4-9bfd9f91fe9f",
  "title": "Unexpected Problem",
  "type": "https://api.weather.gov/problems/UnexpectedProblem",
  "status": 500,
  "detail": "An unexpected problem has occurred.",
  "instance": "https://api.weather.gov/requests/085cf198-e7ee-427c-8bb4-9bfd9f91fe9f"
}
```

If I go to this URL from my web browser or [another service](http://jsoneditoronline.org/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.weather.gov%2Falerts%2Factive), it works just fine. Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with the headers, you can read on the [documentation](https://forecast-v3.weather.gov/documentation) (under API reference) which header you should use for each endpoint and then you simply add them like this:

```
  var headers = {Accept: "application/ld+json"}
  var options = {"headers": headers};
  var currentWeatherUrl = "https://api.weather.gov/alerts/active?active=1"
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(currentWeatherUrl, options);
```